# Local database in j2me midp 1.0

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

I am developing one application in J2me MIDP 1.0

It requires local database management. I have heard about recordStore but can we use it for permanent storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your application can store data using a RecordStore, and you can get it back later even if the application or the phone has been shut down.

EDIT:

One example I found:
http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/read-write-midlet.shtml

Comment: Can We give me some demo Application because i have used  record store  store some data,then agin start my midlet it is not showing That data ,and thank you fro your answer

Answer (score 2):

RecordStore, or more generally, MIDP RMS API is intended just for *use for permanent storage*:

> ...The MIDP provides a mechanism for MIDlets to persistently store data and retrieve it later. This persistent storage mechanism, called the Record Management System (RMS), is modeled after a simple record-oriented database...

If you're interested in more details, refer to [javax.microedition.rms package API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/package-summary.html). Since you mention MIDP 1.0, make sure that you don't use API annotated as `since: 2.0` in these javadocs.

Also, online tutorials are available to get you started, like:

- [MIDP Database Programming Using RMS: a Persistent Storage for MIDlets](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/persist/)
- [Databases and MIDP, Part 1: Understanding the Record Management System](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databaserms/)